# Merging multiple RSS feeds into one

Tags: rss

I have a bunch of RSS feed URLs and I'd like to create a single RSS feed URL that would contain all of these feeds.

Is there a website that does this? Preferably a simple one (not Yahoo! Pipes, please).

Answer (score 2):

[FEEDcombine](http://www.feedcombine.co.uk/st/content/makefeed/):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[FeedStitch](http://feedstitch.com/) might be more to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [xFruits](http://www.xfruits.com/) which can combine multiple RSS feeds into 1, amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

**[FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com)** could be another way to do that. You can make an account for this, and add your RSS feeds as "imaginary friends".

This way, you can have all updates in your "home feed", and get notified directly, or check it as a unique RSS, as explained on [this page](http://friendfeed.com/about/tools), under "Access your FriendFeed".

This solution is adapted when you have a few RSS feeds for which you don't want to miss any update. However, if your use is to have a lot of feeds that you want to watch only from times to times, like news, then this may be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1):

http://feedrinse.com/ is great for this as it not  only combines multiple feeds, it also provides filtering to remove unwanted items or to only allow through items you wish to see